# Apply filter box using conditional formatting

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with the basic Excel filter enabled on the top row (the one under `Sort and Filter` on the ribbon).

When I run a VBA procedure, it clears the data on this sheet and replaces it with new data.  This also removes the filter.

Is there a way I can apply this simple filter drop-down option using VBA by applying it to a range, or conditional formatting?

Comment: I'm not clear on the syntax to apply the filter.

Comment: I am not sure what you're saying... I want to apply the filter dropdown that you get when you highlight a row and click `Sort & Filter` then `Filter`.  Then it puts small filter boxes that the user can manipulate.  I want to have those small filter boxes appear, not do any actual filtering in the VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code will create the kind of autofilter which you may be accustomed to.

Active`Sheet.Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter`